# How to disable hyphenation in all section and subsection titles?

Tags: sectioning, hyphenation

Is there a way to disable hyphenation (splitting up a word) in all section and subsection titles (while leaving hyphenation in the main text unchanged)? They look a bit odd to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package offers an according option.

```
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
```

Details in the package manual. I guess the [sectsty](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package has similar capabilities.

Comment: And if You used `titleformat` from `titlesec` to style titles -- You can do it explicitly: `\titleformat{\section}{\color{teal}\LARGE\raggedright}{\hspace{0.5cm}\thetitle\hspace{0.5cm}}{0cm}{}` (note the `\raggedright`),

Answer (score 9):

try `\section{\sloppy My section title without hyphenating}`

Answer (score 6):

You have to control in template itself:

put `\raggedright` in the section:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\raggedright}}
```