# Section titles, hyphenation, manual line breaks - and how to avoid them

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, hyphenation, titlesec

I have several section titles in my document that are getting hyphenated, which is quite ugly.

I am now looking for some way to avoid the hyphenation, which is is somewhat related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24777/how-to-disable-hyphenation-in-all-section-and-subsection-titles), but unfortunately my titles have to be centered (so `raggedright` is not an option), and adding `\sloppy` to my `titlesec` definition of the subsection format didn't help:

```
\newcommand{\trailthesubsection}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1} (\thesubsection)}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{15pt}{16pt}\bfseries\sffamily\sloppy} % <- "sloppy" didn't help.
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\filcenter\trailthesubsection}
```

I *could*, of course, set manual linebreaks - but in order *not* to destroy the layout of my TOC in the process, I would have to use the optional parameter to the section commands:

```
\subsection[Could do this but it is not nice]{Could do this\\ but it is not nice}
```

Isn't there some way to suppress hyphenation for a given text (e.g. by some command in the `\titleformat`), or to suppress manually-set linebreaks in the TOC?

Comment: While the proper way to handle this is avoiding line breaks in the title, it's worth mentioning the package option `newlinetospace`, with does what the name suggests in headlines and tocs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this question](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff) in the TeX FAQ for a discussion of four different methods for turning off hyphenation. Method three and four consist of adding the instructions

```
\righthyphenmin62 %% or whatever's large enough ...
```

and

```
\hyphenchar\font=-1
```

respectively. The latter approach is used in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\sloppy\bfseries\Large\hyphenchar\font=-1}
\begin{document}
\section{Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 
   Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 
   Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 
   Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 
   Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious }
 
\ldots with apologies to Julie Andrews.
\end{document}
```

Note that the `\sloppy` command will prevent TeX from creating (seriously!) overfull lines in the section title.

**Note** (thanks to egreg): the `\hyphenchar\font-1` instruction is global, so *all*  other text in the document set in `\bfseries\Large` will also see hyphenation suppressed -- which may (or may not) be what's desired. Therefore, the `\righthyphenmin62` method may be marginally safer to use (pun intended). However, according the TeX FAQ's answer noted earlier, if you're a `babel` user the method of resetting the \left- and/or \righthyphenmin macros won't work as `babel` resets them internally.

**Addendum:** To prevent hyphenation in the optional shortened section title (to be displayed in the table of contents), one would have to insert the instructions

```
\protect{\hyphenchar\font=-1}\protect\sloppy
```

at the start of the material in the optional argument of the `\section` command. (My feeling is that if a section caption is longer than one line, it's probably wise to provide a shortened caption that's short enough not to need a line break at all.)

Comment: I read that part of the FAQ, but didn't come up with the idea to use `\hyphenchar\font=-1` *within the titleformat definition*. (I dismissed it as "I don't want to disable it for the whole font / document".) Indeed a most elegant solution for a no-longer existing problem...

Comment: You're welcome! I've inserted an addendum in my answer, in which I explain how one would suppress hyphenation of the section caption in the table of contents.

Comment: Remember, though, that `\hyphenchar=-1` is a *global* declaration. So no other part of the document in `\bfseries\Large` will be hyphenated. I'd prefer `\righthyphenmin=62`, which is a local declaration and will do the same.

Comment: Good point! I'll add this to the answer above.

Answer (score 4):

One way that work is

```
\newif\ifintoc
\DeclareRobustCommand{\titlebreak}{%
  \ifintoc
    \unskip\space
  \else
    \newline
  \fi}
```

Then do the Table of Contents by

```
\begingroup\intoctrue
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

and your title can be input as

```
\subsection{Could do this\titlebreak but it is not nice}
```

It's also possible to inject `\intoctrue` in the code for `\tableofcontents`.

LaTeX will write `\titlebreak` in the `.toc` file, but when this one is read in, `\titlebreak` will mean "leave a normal space". During normal processing of the document it will mean "break line here". The `\unskip\space` is to prevent a double space in

```
 \subsection{Could do this \titlebreak but it is not nice}
```

or no space in

```
 \subsection{Could do this\titlebreak but it is not nice}
```

Comment: I am interest in a minimal working example that shows the effect. I am not able to create one with a hyphenated section.

Comment: *Much* better already... I have this *nagging* memory that I read some other solution not too long ago but didn't really pay attention (or set a bookmark)... I keep the question open for a while to see if someone else has some even more elegant solution.

Comment: @Marco: ...and there I was, going "hey d'oh, I have examples right here"... Then I found that I got things mixed up. I have hyphenated *sections* (but those are block-set and thus easily solved with `\raggedright), and hyphenated *subsections* where the hyphenated words are too long to fit the column in the first place (so it's not a matter of suppressing anything, but chosing shorter words)... so your legitimate request for a MWE just evaporated my problem. I'm ashamed...