# Don't split words in section title

Tags: sectioning, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable hyphenation in all section and subsection titles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24777/how-to-disable-hyphenation-in-all-section-and-subsection-titles)
>   [No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67571/no-hyphen-for-a-word)

How to I tell LaTeX not to split words in section title? For example:

```
\section{Protokol CAN in ISO/OSI referenčni model}
```

... gets printed as "Protokol CAN in ISO/OSI referenčni mo-del". How do I tell him to put last word in new line? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See the solutions provided in [No hyphen for a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571/5764). As a quick-fix, I would use `\mbox{model}`.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Making the words un-breakable may lead to underfull or overfull boxes. I would say that the best solution is to make the section headers `\raggedright`, which ensures that they break only at spaces and no bad boxes are introduced. As well, it looks better than the hyphenates section titles IMO.

**Recommanded solution** with [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. Put this code into your preamble:

```
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
```

**Solution** with no package. This redefines the inner section commands to use `\raggedright`. Put this code into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}
  {\normalfont\raggedright\Large\bfseries}}
\def\subseciton{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
  {\normalfont\raggedright\large\bfseries}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}
  {\normalfont\raggedright\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```